# Accessing child state using Refs - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Newbie to React:

**Error**
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This occurs after I click on one of the Cell components. I'm wanting to print this.tl.state.value to the console.

**Parent Component**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tl = React.createRef();
  }

  checkForWinner = () => {
    console.log("Checking for winner..." + this.tl.state.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Cell ref={this.tl} winnercheck={this.checkForWinner} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class Cell extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: "X"
        }
    }

    toggleVal = () => {

        this.props.winnercheck();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.toggleVal()}>
                {this.state.value}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the value of a ref, you need to use `ref.current`. In your case, that would be `this.tl.current`. Read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for more information.